# C# JSON deserialize into complex class

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON like this

```
    {
  "Application": [
    {
      "Office": "London",
      "LogPath": [
        "\\\\server1\filepath\\"           
      ]
    },
    {
      "Office": "Paris",
      "LogPath": [
        "\\\\server2\\logpath1\\",
        "\\\\server2\\logpath2\\"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "MailSettings": {
    "MailTo": "mymail@mydomain.it",
    "MailSubject" :  "Log Checker"
  } 
}
```

and i have create a custom class to read the json content :

```
public class RootObject
  {
    public Application Application { get; set; }
    public MailSettings MailSettings { get; set; }
  }

  public class Application
  {
    public List<Offices> Offices { get; set; }
  }

  public class Offices
  {
    public string Office{ get; set; }
    public IList<string> LogPath { get; set; }
  }

  public class MailSettings
  {
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public string MailSubject { get; set; }
  }
```

But when i try to deserialize the json with

```
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

I return the error :
the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Which is wrong with my custom class ?

Comment: Your JSON does not match your class structure. For example, your JSON has an array of `Application` properties while your class structure has one `Application` which has a `List<String> offices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom classes should be like it.

```
 public class Application
    {
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public List<string> LogPath { get; set; }
    }

    public class MailSettings
    {
        public string MailTo { get; set; }
        public string MailSubject { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Application> Application { get; set; }
        public MailSettings MailSettings { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate types using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) - to save hand-crafting a representation of the JSON object.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Application> Application { get; set; }
    public MailSettings MailSettings { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public List<string> LogPath { get; set; }
}

public class MailSettings
{
    public string MailTo { get; set; }
    public string MailSubject { get; set; }
}
```

Using Visual Studio "Paste JSON as Classes" gives you the equally functional, but slightly different:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Application[] Application { get; set; }
        public Mailsettings MailSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mailsettings
    {
        public string MailTo { get; set; }
        public string MailSubject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public string[] LogPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Visual Studio Code users can get the same feature using the [JSON as Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype), powered by QuickType.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your json string and use visual studio inbuild feature to create custom class for respective json.

***- Goto Edit -> Special Paste -> Paste JSON as Class***

This will create custom class for you.
Now using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library, you can deserialize your json.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code.your problem is in your RootObject model.
In your RootObject you have a collection of application not single application.
i changed it and it wrok correctly.